# Ext.list.Tree store and templates

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

In Ext JS 6 lists are not there anymore compared to Touch 2.4 Ext.List for example. So what I tried to do now is create a treestore and bind that to a Ext.list.Tree. This seems to work okay though I've no idea how to set a template on the list items. I've the following code:

My model looks like this:

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'phoneNumber', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

Next I've some data:

```
var data = {
    users: [
        {
            name: 'Ed Spencer',
            phoneNumber: '555 1234'
        },
        {
            name: 'Abe Elias',
            phoneNumber: '666 1234'
        }
    ]
};
```

Next is the definition of the store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'User',
    data : data,
    expanded: true,
    defaultRootProperty: 'users',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

And last but not least I bind the store to my treelist:

```
var list = Ext.create('Ext.list.Tree', {
    title: 'simple list',
    store: store,
    width: '200px',
    height: '400px',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    itemTpl: '{name}'
});
```

By looking into the documentation it looks like I need to specify a text property that is then probably automatically displayed in the list, but I do not want to display just text, I want to make a combination of name and phonenumber in this example.

I've no idea how to continue now as I do not know how to display my data in the list/tree. Hopefully someone can help. I've also a Sencha Fiddle available here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1el1

Comment: Your Fiddle doesn't seem to be working. I'm only seeing a blank 200x400 pixel rectangle.

Comment: @SumnerEvans: that's correct, that's part of the problem ;) . I've updated the Fiddle a bit now. I found out there's also Ext.dataview.List that seems to fit my needs better. Though it doesn't seem to fill correctly somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is not to use Ext.list.Tree but Ext.List/Ext.dataview.List instead. I was looking in the classic documentation while I should be looking in the modern documentation.

I now have the following store:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'User',
    data : data,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'users'
        }
    }
});
```

And render the following list:

```
// don't render the list, but add it to the viewport instead
Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('Ext.List', {
    title: 'simple list',
        store: store,
        itemTpl: '{name}, {phoneNumber}'
}));
```

The model and data remains the same.

I've also updated the fiddle so it'll display correctly: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1el1